# Is the condition $\phi(ab) = \phi(b)\phi(a)$ basically equivalent to being a homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory

Let $\phi$ be a map from one group to another. Is the condition $\phi(ab) = \phi(b)\phi(a)$ basically equivalent “up to isomorphism” (or whatever) to the usual condition $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$ of being a homomorphism? Is the correspondence basically given by “do things right to left instead of left to right”?

I’m asking because I was reading Herstein’s proof of Cayley’s Theorem in *Topics in Algebra*, where he considers the map $\tau_g: G \to G$ defined by $\tau_g(x) = xg$, which is right-multiplication by $g$, and then shows that $\tau_{gh} = \tau_h \circ \tau_g$ (here my notation differs from Herstein; by $\tau_h \circ \tau_g$ I mean the map defined by $(\tau_h \circ \tau_g)(x) = \tau_h(\tau_g(x))$). But I thought from the “usual definition”, being a homomorphism should show that $\tau_{gh} = \tau_g \circ \tau_h$. Then when I look up a proof of Cayley’s Theorem (e.g. in Wikipedia), it considers *left*-multiplication by $g$ instead (that is, we define $\tau_g(x) = gx$), in which case we indeed have $\tau_{gh} = \tau_g \circ \tau_h$.

So this made me think that it shouldn’t matter, for all practical/“structural” purposes, whether our condition for homomorphisms was $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$ or $\phi(ab) = \phi(b)\phi(a)$. Am I correct in thinking this? Is there a rigorous justification of this?

Edit: To clarify what I mean: Herstein’s definition of function composition is $(\sigma \circ \tau)(x) = \tau(\sigma(x))$. By this definition, we needed to consider *right*-multiplication by $g$ in the map $\tau_g$ in our proof of Cayley’s Theorem. But by the “usual” definition of function composition as $(\sigma \circ \tau)(x) = \sigma(\tau(x))$, we would need to consider *left*-multiplication by $g$. Does it “just happen” that these two ways of going about things work out the same? Why should Herstein's requirement of homomorphism, which is that $\tau_{gh}(x) = \tau_h(\tau_g(x))$ for all $x$, not affect things -- and basically we just had to do it "from the right" instead of "from the left"? Does this principle hold more generally?

Comment: If we modified the definition that way the identity map would no longer be a homomorphism, not something we want.

Comment: Ok, I understand that the two conditions are not literally equivalent, but I mean, "structurally speaking", would they be equivalent, e.g. "if we read things from right to left" instead (or something similar)? My reasoning is mainly motivated by the example from Herstein I got, which made me think that either way of defining function composition is fine.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antihomomorphism

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3233640/characterization-of-anti-homomorphisms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we have $D_4=\langle a^4=b^2=1, \ bab=a^{-1}\rangle$.

I take $f:D_4 \to D_4$ with $f(x)=x$.

If your definition was right (or at least promising) then $f$ would be a homomorphism.

But $ab=f(ab)=f(b)f(a)=ba$ which is not true.

Hence here, the identity map is not a homomorphism in your sense.